# Go time.Time.UTC() sometimes gives 7 digits, sometimes 9

Tags: go, time

I see some inconsistency in the output of the `time.Now().UTC()` method. Sometimes I get this:

`"created": "2018-10-18T08:50:33.636433623Z"`

And sometimes I get this:

`"created": "2019-05-10T08:16:07.871395Z",`

The difference is the number of digits in the last part. Why isn't this consistent? Does anyone know how I can debug/ensure that it is indeed consistent?

Comment: Because "07.87139500" is not how a fraction is normally rendered. It could have any number of digits depending on the fractional part, not just 7 or 9.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you see less digits in the fraction part of the second, that's because it would end with zeros, and leaving them out does not change the time value.

It looks you were generating those outputs by marshaling some values (containing the timestamps) to JSON. The JSON representation of a [`time.Time`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time) is "governed" by [`Time.MarshalJSON()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.MarshalJSON) which is:

> The time is a quoted string in RFC 3339 format, with sub-second precision added if present.

See this example:

```
t1 := time.Date(2019, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 123456789, time.UTC)
fmt.Println(t1)

t2 := time.Date(2019, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 123456700, time.UTC)
fmt.Println(t2)
```

This outputs:

```
2019-05-10 11:12:13.123456789 +0000 UTC
2019-05-10 11:12:13.1234567 +0000 UTC
```

Marshaling them to JSON:

```
data, err := json.Marshal(t1)
fmt.Println(string(data), err)
data, err = json.Marshal(t2)
fmt.Println(string(data), err)
```

Gives output:

```
"2019-05-10T11:12:13.123456789Z" <nil>
"2019-05-10T11:12:13.1234567Z" <nil>
```

If you want the zeros to appear in the output, use [`time.Format()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Format) and use as many zeros in the format string for the second fractions as many digits you want in the output. This is documented at [`time` package: Constants](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#pkg-constants):

> A decimal point followed by one or more zeros represents a fractional second, **printed to the given number of decimal places**. A decimal point followed by one or more nines represents a fractional second, printed to the given number of decimal places, with **trailing zeros removed**.

`Time.MarshalJSON()` uses `time.RFC3339Nano` which is:

```
RFC3339Nano = "2006-01-02T15:04:05.999999999Z07:00"
```

so trailing zeros are removed. If you use zeros instead of nines in the format:

```
fmt.Println(t2.Format("2006-01-02T15:04:05.000000000Z"))
```

This outputs:

```
2019-05-10T11:12:13.123456700Z
```

Try the examples on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/QWSqONQu9m8).

Comment: Ok cool, I'm a bit further in my investigation now. Turns out that the problem was not in the time package, but it's in the json package of Go. Sometimes the I get 6 digits, sometimes 9. Don't really know when though.

time.Now().UTC() gives